# Griddb CLI build fails

Tags: java, griddb

I have been trying to get a quick rundown of the Griddb Web CLI as specified [here](https://docs.griddb.net/latest/gettingstarted/webshell/#about-the-web-cli) in their quick start guide. I have cloned their [Github repo](https://github.com/griddb/cli) and all is set up. However, on building it using this command:

`gradlew build`

, I get the error attached below indicating that there are some problems that causes the build to fail. I have multiple Java versions installed on my system including Java 8 which does not solve any issues. Has anyone successfully built the Griddb CLI and what might be a problem here?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the Griddb CLI seems to be working on **Java 8**. Since I had several Java versions installed, I solved the problem by:

- Temporarily changing my **JAVA_HOME** environment variable to point to the Java 8 folder
- Building the jar file
- returning the **JAVA_HOME** environment variable value to my previous preferred choice.